# Why does perl not keep the match variable around in this situation?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I just struggled a long time to come up with a working little perl one-liner like this:

```sh
perl -pe 'if (/^(".*",").*, /) { $a = $1; s/, /"\n$a/g}'
```

My input data looks something like this:

```
"foo","bar a"
"baz","bar a, bar b, bar c"
```

And I'm transforming it to this:

```
"foo","bar a"
"baz","bar a"
"baz","bar b"
"baz","bar c"
```

Basically I wanted to only match certain lines (`if (/, /)...`) and on those lines replace all instances of that match with a part of the original line. A `s///g` with a match group would not work because it would not recurse properly, the replacement string has to be figured out before replacements start happening.

```perl
if (/^(".*",").*, /) { s/, /"\n$1/g}
```

Yet it did not. The var `$1` was never anything but empty. Given what the perl [docs I read](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch09_05.htm) said about persistence, this was a surprise to me:

> These match variables generally stay around until the next successful pattern match.

Only when I started stashing the result in a variable of my own could I access the result from the substitution expression:

```perl
if (/^(".*",").*, /) { $a = $1; s/, /"\n$a/g}
```

Why was `$1` being cleared when not only was there no *successful* match, there was no request for a match at all in my search and replace? And would there have been a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

> *Why was $1 being cleared when not only was there no successful match, there was no request for a match at all in my search and replace?*

Are you perhaps conflating *matching* and *capturing*?

For `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` to do anything, the PATTERN must *match*.  So if there is any substitution at all as a result of an `s///` operation, you know that its PATTERN regex-matched successfully.  REPLACEMENT is then evaluated.

(In your case, the `s/, /.../` PATTERN matches at least once on the comma and space after the text `bar a` in your second input line.)

Of course, when that happens, the interpreter will reset all the capture elements (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) to whatever PATTERN captured.  Again, this is before REPLACEMENT is evaluated.  Since your PATTERN doesn't capture anything, those elements are undefined, just as they would be if you had explicitly done a non-capturing `m/, /` match.

Answer (score 4):

The values of match variables do indeed stay around until the next successful pattern match (or until the scope in which the match occurred is exited).

In your case, they changed because there was a successful pattern match. You successfully matched against the pattern `,` . The capture variables will therefore reflect the text captured by the captures of that match. `$1` returns the text matched by the non-existent first capture, so it returned `undef`.

```
$ perl -e'
   $_ = "a";
   s/(a)/a/;  CORE::say $1 // "[undef]";  # Successful match
   s/(c)/c/;  CORE::say $1 // "[undef]";  # Unsuccessful match
   s/a/a/;    CORE::say $1 // "[undef]";  # Successful match
'
a
a
undef
```

Comment: You're not reading the whole question. The documentation I was reading suggests capture variables only get set on SUCCESSFUL match, and can hang around since previous matches. Since I had no match groups in the expression I was surprised that the previous value got blown away.

Comment: Re "*The documentation I was reading suggests capture variables only get set on SUCCESSFUL match*", That is correct. And as my answer both states and shows, there was a successful match.

Comment: Re "*Since I had no match groups in the expression I was surprised that the previous value got blown away*", As you yourself stated, the deciding factor isn't whether there are capture groups or not, it's whether there was a successful match or not

Comment: Your answer demonstrates matching a capture group. My example does not even have a capture group to be successfully or unsuccessfully matched.

Comment: Re "*My example does not even have a capture group to be successfully or unsuccessfully matched.*", Irrelevant. There was still a successful pattern match as I've demonstrated. I've replaced the example nonetheless.